# APNS - Multiple Certificates in one file (dev and production)

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We are developing an **iPhone** application as well as an **iPad** application. 
Both of them do have different Bundle Identifieres but should receive Push Notifications.
The certificates are generated like documented in apples programming guide. 
So, due to the fact that we do have four ceriticates (APNS-Dev-iPhone, APNS-Prod-iPhone, APNS-Dev-iPad, APNS-Prod-iPad) I am wondering how to **combine those certificates** into one file?

The problem is, that on the backend side we are only storing the device token of a user. It is easy to decide whether we are working in development mode or not,but how should I **decide which certificate to use** - the ipad one or the iphone one?

Due to the fact, that we only have the device token, we do not know if the user is using the iPad application or the iPhone one, so **we cannot assume which certificate to use when connecting to the apns apple server**.

Any suggestions on how to handle this issue? Should we store more information - for example the device the user was sending the device token from? Or is there any easier way to combine all the certificates into one file and send it over to the apns apple server?

Thanks in advance, I would appreciate any help!

Comment: you could have created a universal application and used one certificate. but now that you didn't for some reason, you need to store the device type along with the token.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue and have not found a solution that I find satisfactory.

The way that we handle it is similar to what tGilani described. We have to store some kind of identifier that distinguishes which certificate to send a notification through for a particular device token.

Our issue goes further in that we might possibly have to send notifications to different applications altogether. These applications will probably be on a per tenant basis. Thus creating a universal application and one certificate will not work for us.

It would be terribly convenient if I could find a way to combine multiple p12 files into one jks and continue to use one of the Java PNS or Java APNS projects to send notifications.